# When to use spring Boot config server and Netflix archaius?

Tags: spring-cloud-config, netflix-archaius

I am new in microservice architecture. Can anyone please provide use cases like  when to use spring Boot config server over the Netflix archaius and vise versa? What is the exact difference between them ?

Looking forward to your prompt response...

Regards.

Comment: Asking for software recommendations is off-topic for SO. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic